# Could not Load timescaledb-1.6.0.dll - Not a Valid Win32 Application

Tags: database, timescaledb

I've come across an issue when attempting to load timescaledb using PostgreSQL v10.11... Upon executing the following command:

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;`

I'm greeted with the following error:

`ERROR:  could not load library "<postgresfolder>/lib/timescaledb-1.6.0.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

- *postgresfolder* = The path to my postgres installation location.

I've attempted this with PostgreSQL v11.6 aswell, with the same outcome. I don't believe it to be a dependency issue (*Visual Studio C++ Redist. 2015*) as I meet all the prerequisites listed @ https://docs.timescale.com/latest/getting-started/installation/windows/installation-windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(EDIT): The installation is being performed on Windows 10, 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem due to ssleay32 and libeay32 dlls. Get binaries from https://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-11.4-1-windows-x64-binaries.zip and copy them from postgresql-11.4-1-windows-x64-binaries/bin into your /bin folder. If they did not exist, still copy and keep them there.

Also, it looks like timescaledb only works with 11.4 version if you wanna stick with 11.